# Barman postgresql incoming WALs directory

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have got a problem with incoming WALs directory in Barman - backup tool to postgresql databases

In my database server I have in postgresql.conf

```
wal_level = 'archive'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@mybarmanserverip:INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY/%f'
```

In my barman server when I make command "barman show-server myservername" I get, that my `incoming_wals_directory` is

```
/var/lib/barman/myservername/incoming
```

Command `barman check myservername` return "OK" in all points, but when I want to make backup in command `barman backup myservername` I see that first 3 points is correct but point "Asking PostgreSQL server to finalize the backup" never ends.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and that was a problem due to rsync.
To check if it's the case for you, try to rsync a random file :

`rsync -zvh random_file  user@remote_host:/tmp/test`

if the output is something like:

`protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?`

then there is 2 possible reasons :

- 1. rsync versions are not the same on the two servers
- 2. some text is output when you ssh to the remote server, rsync does not like it

To fix the first issue, here is what I did :

- be sure that `rsync --version` is the same on both machines :

  - on your local env run `rsync --version`
  - from your local (to the remote) run `ssh login@remote_host "rsync --version"`

(Install the correct version if they don't match.)

To fix the second issue, you must add something in your `.bashrc` file that prevent text output after ssh connection on non interactive session (i.e "Last login: Thu Sep..." - it makes rsync fail)

I put that at the top of my .bashrc file :

`case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac`

Then rsync works fine, and the initial `barman backup` command finnishes well

Answer (score 0):

replace `INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY` with your incoming folder path which you can find using this command barman show-server main

```
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@mybarmanserverip:/var/lib/barman/main/incoming/%f'
```

Make sure you change the `INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY` placeholder with the value returned by the barman show-server main command above.

Also make sure that postgres user can ssh to barman server correctly.

Comment: please improve this answer